# How to remove changes in a file in hg

Tags: mercurial

Can you please tell me how can I remove change I made  locally?

In git , I can do `git checkout -- aFile.cpp`, how can I do the same thing with `hg`?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

```
hg revert <filename>
```

More detail on available `hg` commands is available on the [man page](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#commands).

(Note that this is not the same as `git revert` - git's revert command is for reverting commits, hg's revert command is for reverting local changes. Also, the command you should really be using to remove local changes in git is actually `git reset`, not checkout.)

Comment: Actually, git reset should only be used when you want to discard _all_ local changes. Michael's git command is correct.

Comment: This does not work during the merge though: `abort: uncommitted merge with no revision specified`

Answer (score 8):

**`revert --no-backup`**

Prevents the creation of `.orig` files, more closely emulating `git checkout`:

```
hg revert --no-backup file
```

See also: [How do you disable mercurial from leaving .orig files after a merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429332/how-do-you-disable-mercurial-from-leaving-orig-files-after-a-merge)